# Thread locking in synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I read that every object in java have a lock.That will be acquired by the thread when a synchronized method is called with that object.And at the same time thread can acquire more than one lock.

```
public class ThreadTes extends Thread{

public static void main(String[] args){

    ThreadTes t=new ThreadTes();
    t.start();

}
synchronized public void r(){
    System.out.println("in r method");
    this.r1();
}
synchronized public void r1(){
    System.out.println("in r1 method");
}
public void run(){
    ThreadTes tt=new ThreadTes();
    tt.r();        
}
}
```

In the above code one synchronized method r() is called from run and then that particular thread acquire lock of that object tt.now again from r() r1() is called.

My question is as tt lock is acquired as it enters into r() then how come it enters into r1() as the lock on that object is already acquired.

```
public class ThreadTes extends Thread{

public static void main(String[] args){

    ThreadTes t=new ThreadTes();
    t.start();

}
synchronized public void r(){
    System.out.println("in r method");
    ThreadTes ttt=new ThreadTes();
    ttt.r1();
}
synchronized public void r1(){
    System.out.println("in r1 method");
}
public void run(){
    ThreadTes tt=new ThreadTes();
    tt.r();   

}
}
```

how come this code is running as i am running with two different objects...

Comment: Here no locking object. code bascially lock the action/methods.

Comment: @Senthil, the object whose lock is used for `synchronized` methods is `this`, whatever `this` is. Static methods use the `Class`'s lock rather than a specific instance's lock.

Comment: as for your latest edit, it's perfectly fine for a thread to own locks from two different objects at once. Each lock entered by one thread cannot be obtained by any other thread until the first thread has finished with it.

Comment: @Mike Daniels..it got clarified..Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's intrinsic locks (used with the `synchronized` keyword) are re-entrant. The lock required to enter `r1` is the same lock as the one required to enter `r`. A thread which already owns a lock is allowed to re-acquire it. You can think of there being a counter for the number of times a thread has acquired the same lock. In method `r1`, the calling thread has acquired the same lock twice. The lock is only available to other threads once the "count" goes back to zero; that is, once the thread that obtained the lock has released it exactly as many times as it obtained it.

**Edit**: Here is an example of five threads that each bounce between two mutually-recursive methods that both require the same lock. By running this example you can see that no thread will enter `methodOne` until the thread before it has completely finished recursing, and that there is no problem for the same thread to continually enter the same (or different) `synchronized` methods that share the same lock.

```
public class LockExample {
    private static synchronized void methodOne(int depth) {
        if (depth == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " methodOne (in), depth " + depth);
            methodTwo(depth - 1);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " methodOne (out), depth " + depth);
        }
    }

    private static synchronized void methodTwo(int depth) {
        if (depth == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " methodTwo (in), depth " + depth);
            methodOne(depth - 1);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " methodTwo (out), depth " + depth);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    methodOne(10);
                }
            });
            t.setName("Thread" + i);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output (sorry for length):

```
Thread0 methodOne (in), depth 10
Thread0 methodTwo (in), depth 9
Thread0 methodOne (in), depth 8
Thread0 methodTwo (in), depth 7
Thread0 methodOne (in), depth 6
Thread0 methodTwo (in), depth 5
Thread0 methodOne (in), depth 4
Thread0 methodTwo (in), depth 3
Thread0 methodOne (in), depth 2
Thread0 methodTwo (in), depth 1
Thread0 methodTwo (out), depth 1
Thread0 methodOne (out), depth 2
Thread0 methodTwo (out), depth 3
Thread0 methodOne (out), depth 4
Thread0 methodTwo (out), depth 5
Thread0 methodOne (out), depth 6
Thread0 methodTwo (out), depth 7
Thread0 methodOne (out), depth 8
Thread0 methodTwo (out), depth 9
Thread0 methodOne (out), depth 10
Thread2 methodOne (in), depth 10
Thread2 methodTwo (in), depth 9
Thread2 methodOne (in), depth 8
Thread2 methodTwo (in), depth 7
Thread2 methodOne (in), depth 6
Thread2 methodTwo (in), depth 5
Thread2 methodOne (in), depth 4
Thread2 methodTwo (in), depth 3
Thread2 methodOne (in), depth 2
Thread2 methodTwo (in), depth 1
Thread2 methodTwo (out), depth 1
Thread2 methodOne (out), depth 2
Thread2 methodTwo (out), depth 3
Thread2 methodOne (out), depth 4
Thread2 methodTwo (out), depth 5
Thread2 methodOne (out), depth 6
Thread2 methodTwo (out), depth 7
Thread2 methodOne (out), depth 8
Thread2 methodTwo (out), depth 9
Thread2 methodOne (out), depth 10
Thread3 methodOne (in), depth 10
Thread3 methodTwo (in), depth 9
Thread3 methodOne (in), depth 8
Thread3 methodTwo (in), depth 7
Thread3 methodOne (in), depth 6
Thread3 methodTwo (in), depth 5
Thread3 methodOne (in), depth 4
Thread3 methodTwo (in), depth 3
Thread3 methodOne (in), depth 2
Thread3 methodTwo (in), depth 1
Thread3 methodTwo (out), depth 1
Thread3 methodOne (out), depth 2
Thread3 methodTwo (out), depth 3
Thread3 methodOne (out), depth 4
Thread3 methodTwo (out), depth 5
Thread3 methodOne (out), depth 6
Thread3 methodTwo (out), depth 7
Thread3 methodOne (out), depth 8
Thread3 methodTwo (out), depth 9
Thread3 methodOne (out), depth 10
Thread1 methodOne (in), depth 10
Thread1 methodTwo (in), depth 9
Thread1 methodOne (in), depth 8
Thread1 methodTwo (in), depth 7
Thread1 methodOne (in), depth 6
Thread1 methodTwo (in), depth 5
Thread1 methodOne (in), depth 4
Thread1 methodTwo (in), depth 3
Thread1 methodOne (in), depth 2
Thread1 methodTwo (in), depth 1
Thread1 methodTwo (out), depth 1
Thread1 methodOne (out), depth 2
Thread1 methodTwo (out), depth 3
Thread1 methodOne (out), depth 4
Thread1 methodTwo (out), depth 5
Thread1 methodOne (out), depth 6
Thread1 methodTwo (out), depth 7
Thread1 methodOne (out), depth 8
Thread1 methodTwo (out), depth 9
Thread1 methodOne (out), depth 10
Thread4 methodOne (in), depth 10
Thread4 methodTwo (in), depth 9
Thread4 methodOne (in), depth 8
Thread4 methodTwo (in), depth 7
Thread4 methodOne (in), depth 6
Thread4 methodTwo (in), depth 5
Thread4 methodOne (in), depth 4
Thread4 methodTwo (in), depth 3
Thread4 methodOne (in), depth 2
Thread4 methodTwo (in), depth 1
Thread4 methodTwo (out), depth 1
Thread4 methodOne (out), depth 2
Thread4 methodTwo (out), depth 3
Thread4 methodOne (out), depth 4
Thread4 methodTwo (out), depth 5
Thread4 methodOne (out), depth 6
Thread4 methodTwo (out), depth 7
Thread4 methodOne (out), depth 8
Thread4 methodTwo (out), depth 9
Thread4 methodOne (out), depth 10
```

Comment: and the critical word that Mike describes but doesn't use is 'reentrant', meaning anyone that holds the lock is able to enter (or re-enter) code synchronised on the same lock.

Comment: @David, thanks. I was fairly sure that was the correct term to use to describe Java's locks but I wasn't positive about it.

Comment: @Mike Daniels great i got it...can i get small example using two synchronized methods to show that same object lock is trying to acquire by two threads.

Comment: public class ThreadTes extends Thread{    
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        ThreadTes t=new ThreadTes();
        t.start();

    }
    synchronized public void r(){
        System.out.println("in r");
        ThreadTes ttt=new ThreadTes();
        ttt.r1();
    }
    synchronized public void r1(){
        System.out.println("");
    }
    public void run(){
        ThreadTes tt=new ThreadTes();
        tt.r();   
    }     }

Comment: @Mike Daniels Thanks for your example ...and can u just check out my edited part and tell me why it is not considered as two different locks from two different objects

Comment: @satheesh, you **are** using two locks from two different objects. There is nothing wrong with this. A thread may obtain as many locks as it needs from as many objects as is required. The only rule is that two threads can't own the same lock at the same time.

Comment: The term "re-acquire" is the wrong term for what is going on because it implies that you are acquiring (again) a lock that you've released.  The correct terminology is that the lock is *reentrant*.

Answer (score 4):

Because the lock is **reentrant**. Owner of the lock(A thread that acquire it) can reacquire it.

> A **reentrant** mutex is a mutual
>   exclusion mechanism. In a reentrant
>   mutex, the same thread can acquire the
>   lock multiple times. However, the lock
>   must be released the same number of
>   times or else other threads will be
>   unable to acquire the lock

Source: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex)

Comment: @satheesh: A reentrant mutex is a mutual exclusion mechanism. In a reentrant mutex, the same thread can acquire the lock multiple times. However, the lock must be released the same number of times or else other threads will be unable to acquire the lock. **source:** [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex).